# Regular Expression (RegEx): Add spaces between each character of surrounded sentence

Tags: regex, eclipse

I am having a difficult time trying to figure out the correct Regular Expression to use to accomplish this task - the RegEx is being used as a FIND/REPLACE in ECLIPSE JUNO on a large file.

Here is the scenario; I have comment lines like this (obviously this is just an example):

```
/********** BEGIN - CODE SECTION **********/
  $code = "Regex";
  echo "<p>{$code}</p>";
/********** END - CODE SECTION **********/
```

And I would like it to look like the following, using the Regex feature of FIND/REPLACE in Eclipse Juno:

```
/********** B E G I N   -   C O D E   S E C T I O N **********/
  $code = "Regex";
  echo "<p>{$code}</p>";
/********** E N D   -   C O D E   S E C T I O N **********/
```

And I've tried many things, including one that I thought was on the right track:

**FIND:**

```
(\*{10}) ([A-Z \-]){1}([A-Z \-])* (\*{10})
```

**REPLACE:**

```
$1 $2 $3 $4
```

...assuming that the space between `$2` and `$3` would do the trick, but what I get instead is:

```
/********** D T **********/
```

I'm new to RegEx (obviously), still learning, and would be very grateful for not only a solution, and an explanation if possible, so that this becomes a learning experience for myself and others.

Thanks!

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

I haven't gotten any responses yet (which is rare in SO after [almost] an hour passes), so I'll break-down, and add an explanation of the RegEx code I was attempting.

- The code `(*{10})` at the beginning and end of the RegEx string selects the 10 asterisks `**********`.
- In the center of the expression, I attempted to FIND and capture where a single UPPERCASE letter (or a hyphen) `([A-Z -]){1}` coming before one or more UPPERCASE letter[s] `([A-Z -])*` occurred.
- Then, I input the REPLACE string, which was to use all four of the "Captured Groups" (with `$1` and `$4` being the opening and closing sets of 10-asterisks...
- ...and remaining two groups representing the found letter `$2`, and the letter which followed it `$3` - but with a SPACE in between them...
- ...which I assumed RegEx would somehow repeat this action for all the letters in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept a regex that only makes sure that ten asterisks *follow*  the text (and ignores whatever precedes it), then you could try something like

**FIND:** `[^*](?=[^*]*\*{10,}/)`

**REPLACE:** `"$0 "` (quotes added to visualize the single space better).

This uses a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure that a `**********/` sequence follows after the current character (which may not be an asterisk). Your approach with repeated capturing groups doesn't work because each repetition overwrites the previous match.

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/dI7xF2).